# SQL want efficient query to SELECT columnA, columnB FROM table1 WHERE both columnA, columnB are in columnC FROM table2 WHERE columndD > value

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I'm searching for a more efficient method to accomplish something that I've already solved with a few different SQL statements.

#### The problem:

I have two tables

1. a transactions table, and
2. an accounts table

The `transactions` table has columns that look like:

| acct_sending | acct_receiving | amount | tx_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 101 | 10 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 101 | 100 | 5 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 101 | 200 | 1 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 200 | 101 | 11 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 200 | 234 | 22 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 234 | 567 | 24 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 567 | 890 | 56 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 890 | 100 | 73 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |

The `accounts` table has columns that look like:

| account | balance | last_tx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 101 | 100 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 102 | 100 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 200 | 1000 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 234 | 10000 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 567 | 1000 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |
| 890 | 100 | yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss |

I want to create a query that returns a list of transactions where both `acct_sending` and `acct_receiving` are in the `accounts` table AND have a `balance` greater than some value. *Bonus points if the query result has a `count` column that holds the total number of transactions between those two accounts.*

Given the `transactions` and `accounts` tables above, if we ran this query with `balance > 10` then the result would be:

| acct_sending | acct_receiving | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 200 | 2 |
| 200 | 234 | 1 |
| 234 | 567 | 1 |
| 567 | 890 | 1 |

---

### My Solution

First, create a temp table with transactions where `acct_sending = account` and `account > 10`

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_sending AS
SELECT acct_sending, acct_receiving
FROM transactions t
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT account
    FROM accounts a
    WHERE t.acct_sending = a.account AND a.balance > 10)
```

Then, create a new temp table using the last temp table where `acct_receiving = account` and `account > 10`

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_sending_receiving AS
SELECT acct_sending, acct_receiving
FROM temp_sending t
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT account
    FROM accounts a
    WHERE t.acct_sending = a.account AND a.balance > 10)
```

Last, I query `temp_sending_receiving` to get a list of unique transactions, and generate the `count` column.

```
SELECT acct_sending, account_receiving, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN sender ELSE receiver END AS sender, 
        CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN receiver ELSE sender END AS receiver 
    FROM temp_sending_receiving
) AS x
GROUP BY acct_sending, account_receiving
```

Running each of these queries gives me the results I want, but ...

### Are there better / more efficient ways to do this?

I'm thinking in both query time, and memory efficiency. Thanks!!!

---

###### Note

I'm running these SQL queries as scripts in DBeaver and Python so I added those as tags. If that's wrong, LMK! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join `transactions` to 2 copies of `accounts` and aggregate:

```
SELECT MIN(t.acct_sending, t.acct_receiving) sender,
       MAX(t.acct_sending, t.acct_receiving) receiver,
       COUNT(*) count
FROM transactions t 
INNER JOIN accounts a1 ON a1.account = t.acct_sending AND a1.balance > 10
INNER JOIN accounts a2 ON a2.account = t.acct_receiving AND a2.balance > 10
GROUP BY sender, receiver;
```

Or, with a `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE balance > 10)
SELECT MIN(t.acct_sending, t.acct_receiving) sender,
       MAX(t.acct_sending, t.acct_receiving) receiver,
       COUNT(*) count
FROM transactions t 
INNER JOIN cte c1 ON c1.account = t.acct_sending
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c2.account = t.acct_receiving
GROUP BY sender, receiver;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z5FdsAzk).

Comment: Ah! That double inner join makes sense now that I'm seeing it. Thanks for pointing out CTE as well. I'm not familiar with that yet, but I'll go read up on it. I'm a little unclear on the use of MIN() and MAX() functions with multiple columns. Is that effectively always returning the smaller account # on the left, and larger account # on the right? I'll come back an up-vote this when I have more rep. :)

Comment: @warp9000 MIN() and MAX() in my query are scalar functions and they return the min and max values respectively of their erguments: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar